# How to get access to the link displaying the name of the app from which a post to the wall has been made?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

you can see a post on my Facebook wall made from inside the Draw Something app. Marked with red ellipse is the link leading to Draw Something Facebook page. As far as i understand this link always shows app's name.  What i wanna find out is how do i access such a link from inside my code? How can i specify this parameter to set there the link i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not done in your code, it's part of the Facebook API. When you go to developers.facebook.com to set up your app with Facebook the name you give them will be the one displayed and the URL for that link will be your app's page.

*That said, I don't know if Facebook allows you to customize this but my guess would be that they don't.